# How to prove that the stable equilibrium has a jacobian matrix of which all eigenvalues are negative OR zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis, physics, vector-fields

Sorry to be sloppy the first time. Now I have corrected something according to the comments.

Let's consider this system of $n$ linear second order ODEs:
$$\ddot {\mathbf{x}}=f(\mathbf{x}),$$
Where $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, and $f(\mathbf 0)=\mathbf 0$. This is the equation of motion of an oscillator with **stable** equilibrium $\mathbf 0$ (not necessarily simple harmonic).

Improtant: $\mathbf 0$ is a **stable** equilibrium.

We can approximate this by $\ddot {\mathbf{x}}=A \mathbf{x}$, where $A=Df_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf 0}$. Intuitively this shoud lead to sinusoidal waveform. However, I struggle to prove this mathematically. To prove that this leads to a sinusoidal waveform, **I just need to prove that all eigenvalues of $A$ are negative OR zero.** Now I have realised that the converse is not true, so just focus on the forward direction.

My attempt: Informally, if the equilibrium is stable, forces should be roughly "directed towards it". $f(\mathbf x)=A\mathbf x$ for small $\mathbf x$, so this translates to, 
$$
\ddot{\mathbf x}\approx -k\mathbf x,k\leq0\\
A\mathbf x\approx -k\mathbf x\\
\mathbf x^TA\mathbf x\approx -k|\mathbf x|^2.
$$
So I *guess* $A$ should be negative definite...or something like that.

**How can I prove that the eignevalues are all negative OR zero?**

Comment: If $n=1$ and $f(x) = x$ then clearly the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ which are not negative, presumably you need more assumptions.

Comment: @copper.hat Read carefully. I have said that $0$ must be a **stable** equilibrium.

Comment: I read carefully, and English is my first language. Unfortunately, I cannot read what has not yet been written.

Comment: If $f(x) = -x^3$ then the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero. It is not clear to me how you can show $A$ to be negative definite.

Comment: The claim in the title is false, a stable equilibrium can have zero Jacobian, it will be stable due to higher order effects as with $f(x) = -x^3$. But this applies to $\dot {\mathbf{x}}=f(\mathbf{x})$, not to $\ddot {\mathbf{x}}=f(\mathbf{x})$. The latter has to be rewritten as a first order system to apply the linear stability theory. Even for $\ddot {\mathbf{x}}=A \mathbf{x}$ with negative definite $A$,  $0$ is only marginally stable (eigenvalues of the first order system are purely imaginary).

Comment: @copper.hat I have written the word "stable" *at the first place*. The fact that I have added one sentence about it later does NOT mean it was not written before you see it the first time. If you do not believe me, LOOK AT the edit history.

Comment: Now I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility...
Assume that $A$ has a positive eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$, so $Av = \lambda v$ for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If ${\bf 0}$ is a stable equilibrium point, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that if the initial condition starts within the closed $\epsilon$-ball about ${\bf 0}$, it will remain in that $\epsilon$-ball.  Suppose that $x(0) = {\bf 0} + \epsilon v$ and $x'(0) = 0$.  Then it suffices to show that $||x(t) - {\bf 0}|| > \epsilon$ at some time $t > 0$.

Looking at the linear approximation of $f$ about the origin, the approximate differential equation is $x''(t) = Ax(t)$, and so initially we have $x''(0) = \epsilon Av = \epsilon \lambda v$, meaning that it will have positive acceleration in the $v$ direction.

Sure, there are minor details omitted, but hopefully you understand the argument as to why the derivative matrix can not have a positive eigenvalue?

Comment: Could you add some details here? I am trying to follow your sketch of proof, but failed because there is **no guarantee** that the particle's position vector will always be on the direction of the eigenvector $v$. It may get onto some other direction and then stay in the $\epsilon$-ball.

Comment: True, it may start on another eigenvector and decay toward the equilibrium point and therefore stay in the $\epsilon$-ball.  But then I would have to ask before adding details, what is your personal working definition of a stable equilibrium point?  Do all trajectories have to diverge away from the equilibrium point [which is not the standard definition]?

Comment: You can just use the standard definition -- I don't ask for anything non-standard. I use the definition here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289969/stability-of-the-solution-mathbf-x-0-of-the-de-ddot-mathbf-x-a-mathbf-x

Comment: Great, then its clear.  Fix an $\epsilon > 0$.  You assume its stable, therefore there exists a $\delta$-nbhd such that all trajectories in that neighborhood will remain $\epsilon$ close to the origin.  Then you look at a trajectory starting on an eigenvector that has a positive eigenvalue.  Since $Av(t) = \lambda v(t)$, then at any time in the future you know the direction. Yes?  If for some reason this still bothers you, then assume that it changes direction at some point and prove a contradiction.  Or perhaps rigorously formulate exactly your personal confusion, and post as a new question.